# In Flutter Which method gets called when pop back to Screen A from Screen B

Tags: flutter, dart, onbackpressed

I have updated my Sqlite Table in Screen B and want to reflect that change in Screen A Also.
So when Pop back from Screen B> Screen A nothing updated.
In Android, we have onResume() to make changes reflect in Activity A.

I have used  Widgets Binding Observer but it works if app background, foreground.

Navigator.of(context).pop();

Comment: Can you post some code of what you tried?

Comment: Also, I assume you mean you tried this (https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/flutter-for/android-devs#how-do-i-listen-to-android-activity-lifecycle-events) looking for the resume enum from https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/AppLifecycleState-class.html?

Answer (score 0):

You can await Navigator.push, when pop is called anything below Navigator.push will be called. Ex:

```dart
await Navigator.push(SomePage());
/// This will be called after SomePage cals Navigator.pop();
doSomething();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get back from the `second page` with data like this:

```dart
// Second Page
Navigator.pop(context, 'result');
```

Then by the below code on the `first page`, you are able to lunch the `second page` and wait until return from it and get data.

```dart
// First Page
var result = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
);
```